# Ambiguous instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just write a simple code in Haskell,

```
coo x y = ((lim-1)*y*(y-1)`div`2) + (y*(y-1)*(sum (map (\j->(x`div`j)-j)  [2..lim] )))
  where
    lim = floor (sqrt x)
```

but when I use 'coo 10 10' in ghci, it gives me the following error:

```
<interactive>:3:1:
No instance for (Floating a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What happened? I am kind of sure I match all types correct.

Comment: You're going to need an explicit type signature for (or within) `coo 10 10` itself. To see why, type `:t coo` in GHCi. The types are correct, but `coo 10 10` is still polymorphic. You'll have to specify whether you want `coo 10 10 :: Float` or `coo 10 10 :: Double`.

Comment: @Rhymoid nope ... although the error would indicate this it is not the problem here - try it: you will just get another error (telling you `Float` or `Double` is not `Integral`)

Comment: `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`; you can use `sqrt (fromIntegral x)`, but be careful of precision loss.

Comment: @Carsten I agree it's not a complete answer, but it is an answer for the immediate problem. Learning how to debug is vital in learning a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely (or ask GHCi) you will see that your function has the type

```
coo :: (Floating a, Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> a -> a
```

telling GHC to use some type `a` that is both a `Floating` and a `Integral` and this will get difficult (there are no such types in the Prelude)

---

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but one way to fix this is to change `lim` into:

```
lim = floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral x)
```

this will yield

```
λ> coo 10 10
360
```

Comment: Could you suggest how to fix this problem?

Comment: done - but I don't know what your function is supposed to be doing

Comment: The proper way would be to implement the [integer square root](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) function.

Comment: @Rhymoid sure but this was not the question here